# How to record FATAL events to separate file with log4perl

Tags: perl, logging, log4perl

I'm using [log4perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log%3a%3aLog4perl) and I want to record all FATAL events in the separate file.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger);

Log::Log4perl::init('log4perl.conf');

my $l_aa = get_logger('AA');
$l_aa->fatal('fatal');

my $l_bb = get_logger('BB');
$l_bb->info('info');
```

And here is my config file:

```
## What to log

    log4perl.logger         = FATAL, FatalLog
    log4perl.logger.BB      = INFO, MainLog

## Logger MainLog

    log4perl.appender.MainLog          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
    log4perl.appender.MainLog.filename = log4perl_main.log

    log4perl.appender.MainLog.layout = PatternLayout

    log4perl.appender.MainLog.layout.ConversionPattern = \
        [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %p - %c - %m%n

## Logger FatalLog

    log4perl.appender.FatalLog          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
    log4perl.appender.FatalLog.filename = log4perl_fatal.log

    log4perl.appender.FatalLog.layout = PatternLayout

    log4perl.appender.FatalLog.layout.ConversionPattern = \
        [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %p - %c - %m%n
```

I'm expecting that with this setup the file `log4perl_fatal.log` will get only FATAL-level events. But here is what I get after running the script:

```
$ tail -f *log
==> log4perl_fatal.log <==
[2014-04-13 08:41:22] FATAL - AA - fatal
[2014-04-13 08:41:22] INFO - BB - info

==> log4perl_main.log <==
[2014-04-13 08:41:22] INFO - BB - info
```

Why I'm getting INFO-level event in `log4perl_fatal.log`?

How can I recordy only FATAL-level events in the separate file?

PS Here is a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bessarabov/log4perl_sample) with this script & config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the question that is coverd in log4perl FAQ — [https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::FAQ#How-can-I-collect-all-FATAL-messages-in-an-extra-log-file](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aFAQ#How-can-I-collect-all-FATAL-messages-in-an-extra-log-file)

In the example `log4perl_fatal.log` gets INFO level events because of appender additivity.

To fix it this line should be added to config file:

```
log4perl.appender.FatalLog.Threshold = FATAL
```

Then the output files get the expected output:

```
$ tail log4perl*log
==> log4perl_fatal.log <==
[2014-05-04 20:00:39] FATAL - AA - fatal

==> log4perl_main.log <==
[2014-05-04 20:00:39] INFO - BB - info
```

Answer (score 2):

Your conf file has the following line:

```
log4perl.logger         = FATAL, FatalLog
```

what you need is the following:

```
log4perl.logger.AA      = FATAL, FatalLog
```

Otherwise, the FatalLog becomes a catch-all for both loggers, instead of isolated to this instance:

```
my $l_aa = get_logger('AA');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm starting to understand. But I still have question. Ok. So in my setup `FatalLog` is a catch-all for all loggers. But why does it record events with level 'INFO'?